# Repeat a character N times

Tags: php, string, repeat

Is there any other way to print 40 dots in php?

I have this in my mind but I think this is wrong.. maybe there was a way like this.

```
<?php print(".",40);  ?>
```

Is it possible to do in that way? without the use of looping?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes ! use the [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) function:

```
echo str_repeat('.', 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any loop then the PHP function `str_repeat()` will work correctly here. Another approach is to do this by the use of arrays.